# How to download Iceweasel

Tags: software-installation

My things will be straigtforward

1. `sudo apt-get update`
2. `sudo apt-get upgrade`
3. `sudo apt get install iceweasel`

Comment: It would be very useful to know what error message you are receiving (if any).

Comment: `apt` and `apt-get` are different commands. Last one should be `sudo apt install iceweasel`. `apt-get`  is legacy, prefer `apt`.

Answer (score 6):

The way I did it was I went [here](https://wiki.debian.orgIceweasel#How_to_install_Iceweasel_.28Firefox.29), the instructions were to run:

```
aptitude install iceweasel
```

But I got a message saying it must be run as root so I ran:

```
sudo aptitude install iceweasel
```

And Iceweasel was installed.

Comment: Iceweasel is **not** Mozilla Firefox. It is a fork of Mozilla Firefox, but they are not the same thing.

Comment: For further details see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mozilla_software_rebranded_by_Debian#Iceweasel) but it came about because the Mozilla branding is incompatible with Debian Free Software Guidelines.  Note that IceWeasel and IceDove (the Thunderbird re-branded EMail client) do not offer updates via the Help menu option but via the package management system - and that add-ons installed via the latter are not up-datable via the built-in add-on updater. You may wish to install add-ons from the application not the package system...!

Comment: @jacobm001 i know that iceweasel and mozilla are different but that is the command it said to run and thats what i ran and it worked. but it was commented with #, so i believe it wouldn't actully do anything.

Comment: You are correct, it doesn't do anything. I would still prefer it was removed from the post since it's wrong.

Comment: alright i wil remove it.

Answer (score 0):

As an update to this Iceweasel is no longer available. Attempting to install it will instead install Firefox. The package for Iceweasel was discontinued in February of 2016. For more information on this please see this [thread](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/49746/whenever-i-install-iceweasel-it-installs-firefox-instead).

To install Firefox start by running:

```
sudo apt-get update && apt-get upgrade
```

Followed by:

```
sudo apt-get icesweasel
```

This will install Firefox **not** Iceweasel.

To install the latest beta version of Firefox:

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

In the file add the following lines of code:

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-mozilla-security/ppa/ubuntu trusty main 
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-mozilla-security/ppa/ubuntu trusty main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/mozillateam/thunderbird-next/ubuntu trusty main 
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/mozillateam/thunderbird-next/ubuntu trusty main
```

Then save the file with exiting. The following command installs Firefox and Thunderbird:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys A6DCF7707EBC211F && sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 9BDB3D89CE49EC21 && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install firefox thunderbird
```

The second method will only work with a Pi 2 or a Pi 3. For more information see [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=150438).

Comment: In the second command, it is `sudo apt-get install iceweasel`