# Whenever I install Iceweasel it installs Firefox instead

Tags: web-browsers

I used the following command to install Iceweasel.

```
sudo apt-get install iceweasel
```

However, instead of Iceweasel, I get Firefox. Not that I'm complaining much, I love Firefox.

If you click on <kbd>Menu</kbd> > <kbd>Internet</kbd>, there are 2 Firefox logos. One says Firefox ESR, and the other says Iceweasel > Firefox ESR.

But I have no idea why it's doing this. Has Iceweasel been discontinued and Firefox linked to the Iceweasel install?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

**TL;DR:** Iceweasel was rebranded *back* to Firefox in Feb '16. You can no longer install Iceweasel.

### Background Info

Firefox is open source. This means that anyone can freely distribute and modify the source code.

However, the laws surrounding the trademark 'Firefox' and the Firefox logo are slightly different. The trademark and logo may only be used with unmodified/official versions of the source code. (This is because Mozilla wants users to have a consistent experience when using 'Firefox')

Debian (the Linux distro which Raspbian is based off) has a set of guidelines called the [Debian Free Software Guidelines](https://www.debian.org/social_contract), which determines what software is allowed to be included in Debian.

Because the restrictions placed on the logo and trademark were not compatible with the guidelines, the distribution of Firefox to be included in Debian had to be rebranded. After many debates etc, the name *Iceweasel* was born and Firefox was rebranded.

However, in February 2016, Mozilla allowed Debian to use the Firefox trademark and logos in their distributions:

> Mozilla recognizes that patches applied to Iceweasel/Firefox don't
> impact the quality of the product.
>
> [...]
>
> In case of derivatives of Debian, Firefox branding can be used as long
> as the patches applied are in the same category as described above.

Hence, Iceweasel was 'un-rebranded' back to Firefox.

### So why can't I install Iceweasel?

Because Iceweasel has been rebranded to Firefox, the Iceweasel package has been discontinued, and instead Firefox is automatically installed. You can no longer install Iceweasel.

### Further reading

- [Wikipedia article on Firefox Trademark laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firefox#Trademark_and_logo)
- [Wikipedia article on Mozilla software rebranded by Debian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mozilla_software_rebranded_by_Debian#Iceweasel)
- [Bug report for renaming Iceweasel to Firefox](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=815006)

Comment: @angussidney, thank you much. This is odd, because yesterday I removed my SD card and reinstalled iceweasel. I also installed it on another SD card only last month. So would you happen to know the sudo command to install Firefox straight up the next time I have to install for whatever reason?

Comment: @BadgerTrucking I assume it is `sudo apt-get install firefox` but I will have to check.

Comment: @angussidney what does this mean for people with Iceweasel already installed? Will they still provide updates or do we need to switch to Firefox?

Comment: @sir_ian I had `iceweasel` installed on a system running the armbian distribution, and it got removed and replaced with `firefox-esr` when I did an `apt-get dist-upgrade`.  I suspect you'll find your copy gets updated the next time there are updates to apply to it (assuming that raspbian is working the same way armbian is).

Comment: You might look [here](https://www.debian.org/security/2016/dsa-3600) for more information about the reason for the change.

Comment: @sir_ian iceweasel is now a [transition package](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/iceweasel), which means that next time when you update, firefox-esr will get installed as a dependency automatically. The email for DSA-3600 says: "Wait, Firefox? No more references to Iceweasel? That's right, Debian no
longer applies a custom branding. [...] Transition packages for the iceweasel packages are provided which
automatically upgrade to the new version."

Answer (score 0):

So here's an update for everyone. I was doing some research. Instead of crapping up your pi with an unneeded install through ice weasel,  simply type in`sudo apt-get install firefox-esr`. You might as well just forget the sudo install command for ice weasel☺️☺️.

Thanks to everyone for their participation in this matter. As always y'all are helpful!!