# What changed in newest Raspbian to affect sound?

Tags: audio, update

I updated to the latest version of Raspbian last night because of [this](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/49746/whenever-i-install-iceweasel-it-installs-firefox-instead) and this morning when i tried to listen to anything it outputs so much static as to be **utterly** unintelligible. And I m talking about more than just the standard terrible sound from the 3.5mm it is like this on the HDMI as well and i have *never* had such poor quality from either.

But what is weird is sonic pi works fine and still sounds amazing but the YouTube sound sucks.

So what changed in Raspbian between  13th May 2016 at 9:15 am, https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/another-update-raspbian/ and sometime around June 3rd so as to **utterly** wreak sound? Because i am pretty certain that I did nothing to break this myself and it worked quite well before i updated *1* and it is now terrible

Doesn't matter which pi I use (I have tried  3 and a 2) so it must be a problem with the OS and the only change that took place between the time it worked and the time it didn't work was it updating. Most videos work but an example of one that doesn't is [weird al polka](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2sr48PsVbS0)

*1*: I was listening to music on YouTube as it was doing its thing

Comment: check sound difference if play a local file. And try a different internet music source. Are you on wifi?

Comment: @dbmitch i used `aplay /usr/share/scratch/Media/Sounds/Instruments/GuitarStrum.wav` to play music and it sounds fine so it might just be youtube and i am definitely on WiFi because i am commenting from my pi

Comment: And now it has stopped on all but one video that i know of... this is crazy.

Comment: What browser?  You may want to check this page: https://www.youtube.com/html5?gl=CA, not that it will say "unsupported" because the sound is bad but it is a clue about some of the complications involved.  Sounds like about the time iceweasel went back to being firefox; I wouldn't think that would make any difference though as in theory they were the same anyway.

Comment: Also check `systemctl list-units | grep pulse` to see if pulseaudio is being used.  You could then try turning that off (`systemctl stop ______`, where _____ is probably `pulseaudio`) and if that fixes things, `systemctl disable pulseaudio`.

Comment: Silly as it sounds, try turning the RPi volume up beyond 75%. I have my reasons: let me know if it removes the static...

Comment: @KDM I have tried that and it is still so bad as to not be able to hear anything. But i have looked at a lot of videos and among the ones that don't work they are almost **all** more than 3 years old

Comment: Hmmm... My RPi 2 was awful below 75% and I found out the reason was teh PWM output. You could try HDMI sound and I'm 100% sure it will be fine. Sorry that's not your answer!

Comment: @KDM I said that it was terrible on all outputs HDMI 3.5 mm and a kingwin USB dac i have